# How do you upload all items in a model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grouped-collection-select

Say I have a form for entering subject marks (separate model) and I want to enter marks for students from a specific classroom from a select box. How do I upload all students based on the classroom I select and have them line up next to marks field

Classroom > One

Student Name  -      Mark

Steve Wonder   -    _______

Roman Reigns   -    _______

Banana Mike    -    _______

Rona Meakins    -   _______

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this. I'll go with the simplest one and let's say you use simple form.

What you basically want to do is something like this:

```
form_for @class do |f|
 # Here you can either loop trough the number of students here or make JS method call from a button to create a new instance of the div below for each student you want to add
  f.simple_fields_for :students do |student_form|
    # Here you have all simple_form methods available
    student_form.input :score
  end
  f.button :submit
end
```